# Linq query with where clause within a where clause causes an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

```
var largeset =
        from inv in context.Invoices
        join line in context.InvoiceLines on inv.InvoiceId equals line.InvoiceId
        into Lines from linejoin in Lines
        join track in context.Tracks on linejoin.TrackId equals track.TrackId
        into Tracks
        select new
        {
            Invoice = inv,
            Line = Lines,
            Track = Tracks
        };

// Filter by search term
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
{
    largeset = largeset.Where(x =>
            x.Invoice.Customer.LastName.StartsWith(SearchTerm) ||
            x.Invoice.Customer.FirstName.StartsWith(SearchTerm) ||
            x.Track.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(SearchTerm)).Count > 0);
}
```

The last line of this code snippet

```
x.Track.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(SearchTerm)).Count > 0
```

is causing an error

> Error CS0019  Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'method group' and 'int'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: should be ``x.Track.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(SearchTerm)).Count()`` as Count is a method not Property

Comment: Thanks Sajjad, that nailed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx

You need to call to method `Count` using `Count()`, instead of just referring to the member name as if it were a property.